# Sonar complains : use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer

Tags: java, append, sonarqube, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I'm currently doing a piece of code which must be able to match some regexp and do some replacement inside the string which match the regexp.

In order to do that I'm using the [matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) object in java. But
as you can see all over internet, all examples use StringBuffer in order to do some replacement using appendreplacement and appendtail method ([oracleDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html)) .

But when I push my code, Sonar complains about using stringbuffer instead of stringbuilder.

- **Is this warning from Sonar is an error in this case?**
- **Is there any library which do the same using stringbuilder?**

Apparently some developpers complains about that [here](https://bitbucket.org/sco0ter/babbler/issues/45/replace-stringbuffer-by-stringbuilder).

I find a way to do not use StringBuffer and use StringBuilder but i'm quite sure this is not as efficient as using StringBuffer (and might be a bad practice). You can copy paste inside a junit test this example code below :

```
    String entry = "Actual 4.11-6 and 13-5";
    String expectedReturn = "Actual 4*11^(-6) and 13^(-5)";

    String number = "(^|\\s)-?\\d+((\\.||,)\\d+){0,1}(.\\d+){0,1}-\\d+";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(number);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entry);

    //USING STRING BUFFER
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String substring;
    while(matcher.find()){
        substring = matcher.group(0);
        matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer,substring.replace(".","*").replace("-","^(-")+")");
    }
    matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);

    //USING STRING BUILDER
    matcher = pattern.matcher(entry);
    int lastIndex = 0;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while(matcher.find()){
        stringBuilder.append(entry.substring(lastIndex,matcher.start()));
        substring = matcher.group(0);
        stringBuilder.append(substring.replace(".","*").replace("-","^(-")+")");
        lastIndex = matcher.end();
    }
    stringBuilder.append(entry.substring(lastIndex,entry.length()));

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedReturn,stringBuffer.toString());
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedReturn,stringBuilder.toString());
```

Info : The matcher which manage stringbuilder for append will be in jdk 9 [source code](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~plevart/jdk9-dev/MatcherWithStringBuilder/webrev.01/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java) and [code review](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sherman/8039124/webrev/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a warning, not an error. Sonar does its job of warning you that `StringBuilder` is preferable [because it is faster](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/StringBuilder.html). If the API forces you to use `StringBuffer` then I would use it and silence the warnings.

I think the real underlying problem with `Pattern` and both buffers is that `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` do not share a specific interface for building strings (`Appendable` is a more generic interface, I think they should share a more specific interface for constructing strings, something like `StringConstructor`), which would allow you to switch implementation with zero effort (usually).

Comment: "StringBuffer and StringBuilder do not share a specific interface". They do: they both implement `Appendable`. Or else I just don't understand what you mean, in which case, could you clarify?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yes, sorry, you're right, that is not clear. `Appendable` is a more generic interface. I think they should share a more specific interface for constructing strings, something like `StringConstructor` or so.

Comment: Well, technically they do too (in OpenJDK). Both extend `AbstractStringBuilder` which, unfortunately, isn't public.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire That is not what official JavaDoc says, which is what counts in the end.

Comment: Indeed, hence the "technically" and the "unfortunately".

Comment: In this case I do think methods taking `Appendable` would have been sufficient. Both `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` build the string by calling `toString()` so switching implementations is simple enough.